# I can't dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, Grub simply doesnt appear

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I tried many ways, enabling, disabling secure boot, my BIOS are UEFI, when in partition screen i already tried to choose as boot initialization the HDD and the Window Bootloader, both doesnt work, the Grub simply doesnt appear, but in the partition screen shows that Ubuntu is installed, i cant even start Ubuntu.
I tried to use a software in Windows EasyBCD that manage bootloaders on PC, but when i run this program a message appear saying that Bootloader EFI was detected so duo to this limitations some resources of multi-initialization are not avaliable.

I dont know what to do, Windows 10 was sealed on my machine or what? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the boot order at which your system boot. If you installed windows first then Ubuntu then this problem. I too had the same problem when i changed the boot to ubuntu then windows, my problem was solved. Once you have done this then login to ubuntu and upgrade your grub. Hope this helps

Comment: Where can i change the boot order? The ubuntu simply doesnt appear as installed in any place, in BIOS only one that appear is Window Bootloader. Ubuntu only appear installed if i use the installation media again and go to partition window, so there appears the partition with Ubuntu LTS 20.0

Answer (score 0):

Just open bios[F2 in Dell and Asus, Esc in Hp, F12 in Lenovo] and change the boot order to 1. ubuntu and then 2. Windows boot manager. Then you can see grub while booting